# Finding the balance of thinking and working

Tags: reference-request, daily-life

Today I realized that I am an overthinker. I postpone things because of thinking, planning. I missed lot of time due it.
But by thinking I found lot of new stuff. Those thinking is the main cause for the posts in this forum.

I think there should be a balance. Without thinking, we may go in the wrong path. With overthinking, work won't complete.

What are the suttas which states this balance? I know the story of Arahant Sona about effort. I really like to know about balance of thinking and working?

Answer (score 2):

Thinking is an essential activity, of course, and it's impossible to avoid doing any thinking.  The key is balance between being centered in the activity of your mind and being centered in your body.  The more time you spend feeling the feelings of your body, gradually the thinking activity will settle down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> With overthinking, work won't complete.
>
> What are the suttas which states this balance?

An 5.73

"Then there is the case where a monk takes the Dhamma as he has heard & studied it and thinks about it, evaluates it, and examines it with his intellect. He spends the day in Dhamma-thinking. He neglects seclusion. He doesn't commit himself to internal tranquillity of awareness. This is called a monk who is keen on thinking, not one who dwells in the Dhamma.

"Then there is the case where a monk studies the Dhamma: dialogues, narratives of mixed prose and verse, explanations, verses, spontaneous exclamations, quotations, birth stories, amazing events, question & answer sessions. He doesn't spend the day in Dhamma-study. He doesn't neglect seclusion. He commits himself to internal tranquillity of awareness. This is called a monk who dwells in the Dhamma.
...
Over there are the roots of trees; over there, empty dwellings. Practice jhana, monk. Don't be heedless. Don't later fall into regret. This is our message to you."